# Python - Im trying to split a tab delimited file by new line, then by tab, then add data in each line at a specific place

Tags: python, scripting, csv

I am trying to split a tab delimited file based on each line, then each tab, then add a piece of text into a specific location in each line.

I.e: 
H123_123 78.752  GREEN  7   0   0   0   0   1   Gene
H1234_1234 23.998   GREEN   9   1   0   0   0   0.92   Gene

Into:

H123_123 78.752  NEW_TEXT GREEN 7   0   0   0   0   1   Gene
H1234_1234 23.998   NEW_TEXT GREEN  9   1   0   0   0   0.92   Gene

```
my_file = open("data.txt", "r+")
output = "data" + "_processed" + ".txt"
outputfile = open(output, "w")

run = NEW_TEXT

lst = []
for line in my_file:
    word = line.split("\t")
    if 'H' in line:
        lst = word[0:12]
        lst.insert(1, run)
        lst.insert(13, "\n")
        print lst
        outputfile.write(str(lst))
my_file.close()
outputfile.close()
```

when this is printed to the terminal it seems to be in the correct format... however the outputfile is all on one row - the "\n" did not work?
Is there a better way of doing this? I have been changing my code around but keep getting different error codes

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outputfile.write(str(lst) + '\n')
```

But if you want to convert the list to string use join() method

```
outputfile.write(' '.join(lst) + '\n')
```

Comment: if this worked for you then you can accept or upvote this :)